# Перестановка одномерного массива чисел

Tags: javascript, алгоритм, комбинаторика, псевдокод

Дан простой массив array = [1,2,3,4,5,6].

Нужно получить всевозможные состояния перестановок от состояния [1,2,3,4,5,6] до [6,5,4,3,2,1].

Но следующим способом: в состоянии выделяются  пары  чисел  (i, i+1). 
Парами являются (1,2), (2,3),... (5,6), (их количество n–1);

Таким образом, всегда может быть сформировано n–1 состояний. На следующем  этапе  в  полученных  состояниях  также  выделяются  пары,  и алгоритм  преобразования  состояний  повторяется  до  условия  окончания поиска.

Как я понимаю, количество перестановок равно n!.

Подскажите, как реализовать такой алгоритм. Можно и в ширину и в глубину, а можно и еще как-нибудь. Неважно на каком языке реализовать (предпочтительно, конечно, js), но можно и псевдокодом даже.

К сожалению, в комбинаторике я очень плох :)

Comment: Непонятно, каким образом подразумевается применение знаний о "состояниях" к генерации следующей перестановки.

Comment: первый этап - из 123456 берется первая пара (1,2). 1 ставиться в начало, а 2 в конец, получим состояние - 134562. Потом берем вторую пару (2.3), получаем 214563. И также пары (3,4), (4,5) и (5,6). Потом второй этап - это из того, что получили в предыдущем этапе, т.е. состояние 134562...начинаем его перебирать...у него пары (1.3) (3.4)(4.5)(5.6)(6.2) и так для каждого состояния

Comment: Ну так если этот алгоритм действительно генерирует все перестановки без повторов, то всё описание его уже есть, и осталось его только реализовать.

Comment: Про без повторов - это не так, достаточно посмотреть на дерево генерации `1,2,3`. Дерево глубиной D дает `((n-1)^D - 1)/(n-2)` вариантов с повторами. Какая глубина генерации нужна, что бы выбрать все n! перестановок?

Comment: Вопрос про глубину, возможно, неправильно понял. Но нужно переставить все пары каждого состояния.

Comment: Так что мешает это сделать?

Comment: Могу дать код на c++, нужно? На JS перевести сами сможете?